# Is it ok for me to post a question detailing the consequences for the GTA series after Dan Houser leaves Rockstar?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

After seeing multiple titles on the internet about any updates for the next GTA 6 release I came upon some bad news.

Apparently, Dan Houser is quitting Rockstar Games.

Multi-Era Vice City is in the dumpster apparently. This is possibly a major setback for GTA6. We may not even see a trailer till 2023. And a release in 2025.

### Question

Is this the fall of the GTA series just as we've seen with other games?

Comment: Is the question in the body the one you're wanting to ask on the main site?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming you're going to ask the question that's at the end of your post: This is a loaded question and we wouldn't accept it regardless of whether the subject itself is on-topic.

Now, if you were to ask "what does this mean for the GTA series?", that's covered by the second entry in [our "what is off-topic" help entry](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> Speculations on future of the industry, upcoming (but unreleased) games or content, and developer intent on mechanics and narrative

We don't allow speculative questions on developer intent because no one can really answer them apart from the developers themselves, and the most we can probably expect from that end is a dismissive comment somewhere in a press release or interview that will just contain platitudes about no individual being vital and the team still having tons of other highly dedicated and passionate developers who will create new and exciting content for the player base.

Comment: I appreciate your answer as it helped me understand what "wording-style" I need for future questions. The big picture will always require some degree of speculation. Otherwise, its down to earth and boring.